# Codeigniter passing array to controller via CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, command-line-interface

I need to run one of my CI scripts on the command-line. I need to pass an array to the controller to then pass to the script. Here's what I've got right now:

```
$params = array(
    'a' => var1,
    'b' => var2
);
```

Then the cmd running is:

```
php index.php process process_opk params
```

In my controller, just to see how/if the array is coming through properly I have:

```
public function index($args) {
    print_r($args);
}
```

and the output of this is `params` as a string.

Do I need to serialize my array first before sending it? I guess CLI changes how variables are passed through CLI, am I wrong? If anyone could elaborate on this and demonstrate best practice, that would be great. Thanks!

**Update:** Best solution I could find so far is to base64_encode the serialized data and send it as a long string. Then in the controller decode and unserialize and send the array to my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default CI allows "a-z 0-9~%.:_-" characters. base64 produces another symbols like + and =. That's why it can be better to use [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/function.rawurlencode.php) instead of base64:

```
exec( 'php index.php controller function '.rawurlencode(serialize($params)) );
```

It's safe for transfering & shell.

Answer (score 2):

If number of parameters are not too many it is convenient to pass parameters like...

```
php index.php process process_opk/par1/par2/par3...
```

and in controller

```
<?php

class Process extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();       
}

public function index()
{
    $this->process_opk();
}

public function process_opk($par1 = -1,$par2 = -1,$par3 = -1)
{
  //process
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I guess CLI changes how variables are passed through CLI, am I wrong?

No.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873015/183254

Your solution seems to be the best route although not sure base64 is necessary (it might be esp if you have wonky characters).

Comment: Well, CI doesn't allow `{ } =` by default and probably more too, so not worth the risk. This is working for what I need atm.

Answer (score 0):

To pass it into a new thread with post data:

```
exec('nohup php index.php controller method ' . rawurlencode($this->input->raw_input_stream) . ' ' . arg2 . ' ' . $arg3 . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $op);
```