# Script to execute commands in sequence php

Tags: php, arrays, bash

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script that will essentially execute one after the other (provided the previous command has finished).

```
php bin/console SOME:CUSTOM:COMMAND <PART_1_ARGUMENT> <PART_2_ARGUMENT> --env=xxx
```

- The following is fixed and I need to pass in say a list of variables in-between

  - php bin/console COMMAND --env=xxx

e.g. lets say I have the following as my arguments

- Apple pie
- Apple crumble
- Pear apple

then my command would work in order executing one after the other like

```
php bin/console COMMAND Apple pie --env=xxx
```

and then right after

```
php bin/console COMMAND Apple crumble --env=xxx
```

and so forth ?

Any info is helpful I've googled for hours .. (newbie)

Comment: Just put the two commands right after each other in a shell script.

Comment: Can't you just pass them as a list of arguments, and in your PHP script, loop through the inputs and call your logic/function for each input.

Comment: Not really sure if it's exactly a "duplicate", but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872755/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-array-as-a-command-line-argument-to-a-php-script) which a quick search turned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
for args in "Apple pie" "Apple crumble" "Pear apple"
do
    php bin/console COMMAND $args --env=xxx
done
```

One caveat: this won't work if any of the arguments can contain whitespace or wildcard characters. You can't quote `$args` in the command line, because you need `Apple` and `pie` to be separate arguments. It wouldn't work to put quotes in the strings, because quotes aren't parsed when expanding variables. You could do it with two arrays:

```
arg1=("Apple" "Apple" "Pear")
arg2=("pie" "crumble" "apple")

for (( i=0; i < ${#arg1[@]}; i++ ))
do
    php bin/console COMMAND "${arg1[$i]}" "${arg2[$i]}" --env=xxx
done
```

Comment: very useful! I compared what I had, I had a bunch on extra brackets etc. But knowing that about the "whitespace" I didn't know. It's 90% there I will work on trying to get it done because the loop doesn't fully cycle. It stops after the first one :)

Comment: I just removed the 

    let i=i+1 

And the rest fell into place .. Thanks for your support @Barmar

Comment: that was left over from an earlier while loop